# EF POCO's can't update navigation property

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using EF5 with MVC and POCO's and need a little help

I have an update function which is passed a disconnected POCO. The POCO has a 'navigation property' collection, eg: Provider has

`public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }`

When the Provider was loaded (and the old context closed) it had two Company objects, now it has four and I'd like to update.

I thought the code below might work but **Companies is not updated** (but the non-navigational properties of Provider (like string Name {get;set} are still updated ok) **and there is no error**

```
public void Update(Provider entity)
{                        
            // Existing entity
            _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

            if (entity.Companies.Any())
            {
                //try to tell EF about the companies
                foreach (var company in entity.Companies)
                {
                    //the company exists already - let the context know....                        
                    _context.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    _context.Companies.Attach(company);
                }
            }                    
}
```

... and later: `_unitOfWork.SaveChanges();`

For an insert of Provider with Companies I had successfully used:

```
if (entity.Companies.Any())
{
    //these are not to be created - they exist - 
    //I want EF to add them as nav properties
    foreach (var company in entity.Companies)
    {
        //the company exists already - let the context know....
        _pvpContext.Companies.Attach(company);
    }
}

// New entity
_pvpContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
```

I'm going to go and read Julia Lerman's book as EF is killing me - but I'd really appreciate any help updating 'Companies' in the meantime - Thx

Edit:
Taking @Manos' kind advice I tried:

```
List<Company> companies = new List<Company>();
if (entity.Companies != null && entity.Companies.Any())
{
    //pull out the Companies from the POCO
    companies = entity.Companies.ToList();

    //remove them
    entity.Companies = new Collection<Company>();
    entity.Companies.Clear();
}

// pass existing entity to the context, tagged as modified
_pvpContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

if (companies.Any())
{
    //now re-add the companies while the context is listening. ffs.
    foreach (var company in companies)
    {
        entity.Companies.Add(company);
    }
}
```

If I add the Provider.Companies to the context (like in the insert) I get:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__tmp_ms_x__679519B7F943FD8D'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ProviderCompany'. The
>   duplicate key value is (5, 3)

- which is odd as there is not composite key of (provider 5, company 3) - so maybe it's trying to add it in twice here?

If I don't pre-add the Provider.Companies I get:

> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I only have 4.1 to test, but try this as a basic logic:

```
public void Update(Provider entity)
{                        
    // Existing entity
    Provider contextProvider = _context.Entry(entity);
    contextProvider.Companies.Clear();        

    foreach (var company in entity.Companies)
    {
        contextProvider.Companies.Add(company);
    }

}
```

This needs a little refinement in order to only add new companies as opposed to doing a complete removal and reinstatement but it should work.

**Edit in response to comment:**

Try catching the exception thrown by SaveChanges() with the following:

```
try {
    _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
} catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException e) {
    foreach (var k in e.EntityValidationErrors) {
        foreach (var e1 in k.ValidationErrors) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", e1.PropertyName, e1.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

It should give you a little more information to go on.

Comment: Thanks Manos, unfortunately I'm getting an odd exception after my _unitOfWork.SaveChanges(): "at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()"

Comment: Does the exception have a message?

Comment: Yes it's "{"Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."} System.Exception {System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException}". I've no idea where EntityValidationErrors can be found :(
"

Comment: Thanks, that really helped - the errors are to do with me using stub entities for Company eg: Company is not fully hydrated - it just includes the Entity key (which I thought was all that was needed for an existing object).

Comment: I eventually reworked what I had and now it works, mostly thanks to your help. I'd hoped that EF was intuitive to use without a full understanding but it's not. On the plus side, Julia Lermans DbContext book is helping me a lot so hopefully I'll be ok from here. Thanks again.